# Can we create an array while passing it as an argument to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, oop

I want to create an array while passing it to a function, like we can do in Java or Python.
For example:

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example(new int[]{1,2,3});   // Like this
    }
    static void example(int[] a){
        System.out.print(a[0]);
    }
}
```

or in python

```py
def fun(x):
    print(x[0])

fun((1, 2, 3)) #Like this
```

When I try to do something like this in C++ I get an error

```cpp
void example(int a[]){
    cout<<a[0]<<endl;
}

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    cout << "Hello world!"<<endl;
    example(new int(3){0, 1, 2});
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the error

> error: expected ')' before '{' token

or

```cpp
void example(int a[]){
    cout<<a[0]<<endl;
}

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    cout << "Hello world!"<<endl;
    example({0, 1, 2});
    return 0;
}
```

Here the compiler takes the array `{0, 1, 2}` as an initializer list.

> error: cannot convert '' to 'int*'

I'd like if there is some way of achieving a function call similar to the 2nd attempt.

```
function({1, 2, 3, 4});   //An array of any size
```

I tried searching for it but wasn't able to find a solution that fits the bill.
Any and all help is really appreciated and I thank everyone in advance.

Comment: PSA: Use `std::vector` and stop slinging C-style arrays around as pointers. Stay away from `new[]` if you can.

Comment: `example(new int(3){0, 1, 2});` is, syntax aside, allocating, using, and then **failing to release memory**. It is important you never do this. If you allocate you **must** assume responsibility to release the memory.

Comment: `int(3)` is not an array. It is a single int with the value 3.

Comment: `example(std::array{0, 1, 2}.data());`?

Comment: But `void example(std::span</*const*/int>)` would probably be better.

Comment: It seems you are learning C++ the wrong way. `new` in Java and `new` in C++ do very different things. Don't just code at random and hope for the best and don't use other languages as a templates when learning a new language. Get [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a reworked version that uses more modern C++ conventions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void example(const std::vector<int>& a) {
    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Using a pre-defined variable
    std::vector<int> list { 0, 1, 2 };

    example(list);

    // Using an inline variable
    example(std::vector<int> { 3, 4 });

    // Letting the compiler figure it out
    example({ 5, 6 });

    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind `new[]` is **not** automatically released, and if you pass it in as an argument to a function that does not assume responsibility for releasing it, you have a memory leak.

This does not happen with `std::vector` or other standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), these will always release memory when they fall out of scope.

Python will fill in the blanks in many ways that C++ refuses to, but even Python can be made stricter about arguments where it will act a lot more like C++.

Comment: `example({3, 4});` will work too

Comment: @Chad I thought that only works in constructors, so kind of amazed. Updated with that information.